# udev and usb framebuffer device

Tags: usb, framebuffer, udev

I want to get a fixed device-name for a certain USB Framebuffer device (DisplayLink). Using the vendor-ID I can get a match using a udev rule:
 SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="17e9", GROUP="video"

But with SYMLINK+="fbdl" I do NOT get a symlink to the /dev/fbX device (X=1,2,3..), but to bus/usb/... - which is NOT the same: using this device-file (link) does not work in xorg.conf. Setting a NAME instead of the SYMLINK is the same: the real device /dev/fbX stays there and works, the given NAME is created additionally, but is some other target (does not work). What is going on here?? In case of things like /dev/input/eventX with SYMLINK you get a link to that eventX. Why not here?

Thanks!
(Ubuntu 11.04)

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, you'll also need a KERNEL match like follows:

```
# udev rule for MiMo
KERNEL=="fb[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="17e9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="401a", \
SYMLINK+="mimo", RUN+="displaylink.sh"
```